Get everyday data in hourly group using sql
I have a mysql table which has two columns id and attendancetime, I want to select count(id) hourly.



id
attendancetime




1
1725256398


2
1725258398


3
1725264581


4
1725277777


5
1725277777


6
1725277777


7
1725298931


8
1725299156


9
1725299156



My expected result is:



TIME
COUNT




11:00
2


01:00
1


05:00
3


11:00
3



I have tried following query:
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(attendancetime)), ' ',
        LPAD(FLOOR(HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(attendancetime)) / 3) * 3, 2, '0'), ':00:00'
    ) AS TIME,
    count(id) AS COUNT
FROM operationallog
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(attendancetime)), FLOOR(HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(attendancetime)) / 3)
ORDER BY TIME;

Please provide mysql query to achieve this result

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Please check my attempted query now

My expected result is ?? it does not match both provided sample data and query text.

use GROUP BY attendancetime DIV 3600

Maybe you need in
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(attendancetime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00') date_time,
       COUNT(*) amount
FROM tablename
GROUP BY 1;

?

This looks both the cleanest and most efficient way:
Integer divide the Unix epoch by 3600, and multiply by 3600 again, to truncate to the hour, and use from_unixtime() on the result to get the hour obtained converted to timestamp, then group by that expression and aggregate COUNT(DISTINCT id)  on that grouping:
WITH
indata(id,attendancetime) AS (
          SELECT 1,1725256398
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1725258398
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1725264581
UNION ALL SELECT 4,1725277777
UNION ALL SELECT 5,1725277777
UNION ALL SELECT 6,1725277777
UNION ALL SELECT 7,1725298931
UNION ALL SELECT 8,1725299156
UNION ALL SELECT 9,1725299156
)
SELECT
  from_unixtime((attendancetime DIV 3600)* 3600) AS thehour
, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS idcount
FROM indata
GROUP BY 1;                                        




thehour
idcount




2024-09-02 05:00:00
1


2024-09-02 06:00:00
1


2024-09-02 08:00:00
1


2024-09-02 11:00:00
3


2024-09-02 17:00:00
3



fiddle
